# arcsin with a negative value

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to find out the result of `arcsin` with a negative number (for example: `arcsin(-0.5)`). If I use calculator, it is giving negative value (-0.52359878 rad). However, I need the result(in radian) to be positive value. I tried some online calculators that also shows positive result (3.66519143 rad). Would anyone please suggest the method/formula to find out the positive result without using online calculator.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you aware of how the sine is periodic? I.e. $\sin(x+2\pi k)=\sin(x)$ when $k\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\sin(\pi-\alpha)=\sin(\alpha)$, if $\sin(-0.52359878)\approx-0.5$, $\sin(\pi+0.52359878)\approx-0.5$. And $\pi+0.52359878\approx3.66519143$.

Answer (score 2):

The function $\arcsin$ is defined on $[-1,1]$ and with values on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. If you want the two positive answers on $[0,2\pi]$ for $\sin(x)=\alpha$ with $\alpha \in [-1,0]$, you just take $\pi-\arcsin(\alpha)$ and $\arcsin(\alpha)+2\pi$.